# What's the difference between ChannelDuplexHandler and WebSocketServerProtocolHandler in netty4?

Tags: java, netty

I want to realize a duplex protocol between client and server. Websocket protocol is an appropriate protocol for this case. However, when I check the netty4 API doc, I find that there is a class called ChannelDuplexHandler which seems also a good choice for a duplex protocol.

What's the difference between them and how I decide which handler to use?

Answer (score 0):

- `WebSocketServerProtocolHandler` extends  `WebSocketProtocolHandler` which extends `MessageToMessageDecoder<WebSocketFrame>` which finally extends `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter`,
- while `ChannelDuplexHandler` is a mix of `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` and `ChannelOutboundHandlerAdapter`

So the difference is the first one is only Inbound, while the second is both Inbound and Outbound. Maybe you give a different meaning to "duplex" here (duplex means here both ways within Netty)?